# How can you edit SharePoint metadata from C#?

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I've been looking at using the [Administration Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms492509%28office.12%29.aspx) but it doesn't seem to get into this.

Can anyone recommend tutorials or point me in the right direction to get this going?

Comment: What do you mean by edit share point metadata? Can you provide an example....

Comment: I'm not sure how else to describe it (i'm very new to SP).  I've heard it also referred to as indexes.  Basically custom fields you create that allow people to enter custom information about a document.

Comment: Ashish, here is a good link explaining what metadata is: http://blog.contentmanagementconnection.com/Home/20563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to do this by using the SPListItem.Update() method.

Example:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mySPSite/");
SPList oList = site.AllWebs["Main"].Lists["Documents"];
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.Query = @"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Published' /><Value Type='Text'>0</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
{
    oListItem["Published"] = 1; //These two lines will do the update.  In this case I am updating Published to 1
    oListItem.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Managed Metadata (a new feature of SharePoint 2010), this could be your gateway: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556337.aspx.

The term "Metadata" is also used for any custom attributes you want to specify to items (or documents) in SharePoint environment. Usually such metadata is logically aggregated into a SharePoint construct called Content Type which is attached to an SharePoint item (or a document in SharePoint Library).

If you are programmatically create document in document library and also set the metadata for the document, this link may help: http://geek.hubkey.com/2007/10/upload-file-to-sharepoint-document.html

If it is not a document library but a custom list (with specific content type attached to it), you may find plenty of resources on google when you type "Add List Items to the Sharepoint List Programmatically"

If you are new to SharePoint, I understand it is quite a learning curve for you. After working with Microsoft Technologies for years, I think being a Proficient SharePoint Developer involves longest learning curve even if you are a seasoned C# developer.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Ashish Patel
Take a look to the following article if you are talking about metadata in sharepoint 2010

[Managed Metadata in SharePoint 2010 – a key ECM enhancement](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/12/managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010-key.html)

Regards,

Comment: Best as a comment to what it applies to.